# Possible to Tie Keyboard Input to a Single Application in Win32?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, input

I have a rather unusual Windows project for a client that has led me to believe that what we're trying to accomplish may not be possible. We're at a point where we would like to have the application listen for input from a proprietary keyboard device and process it. This application runs in the background and always listens using an input sink with raw input.

Since the device is a keyboard, the foreground window always gets the input and our application will hear it as well. Ideally, we would like ours to be the only one that hears input from the device. As far as I could research, there doesn't seem to be any way to tie input from a specific device to a specific application and make every other application ignore it. I saw `BlockInput()` but that shuts down user input from every device.

Is this even possible?

EDIT: To clarify some things, the device is seen as a keyboard by the system and I am able to use raw input to detect it as a keyboard and get the keystrokes. As a keyboard device, any foreground window will receive keystrokes when the user interacts with it. The application listens for keystrokes from that device before taking a specific action. I only want the application to receive input.

Comment: Is this keyboard `USB`? Furthermore, if it's proprietary does it require a custom `driver`?

Comment: You can use [Raw Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/raw-input) to read input from specific devices.

Comment: You can use Raw Input to identify input on a specific device, and then use `SetWindowsHookEx()` to block input from reaching windows. Keeping the two APIs in sync is not trivial, but doable.

Comment: @WBuck - The keyboard communicates with Bluetooth. Once connected to the system, it's identified as a keyboard in the list of devices.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter - I do use raw input to identify the device and only perform a specific action when that device sends input. However, since it's seen as a keyboard, it functions like any other keyboard once connected to the system. Windows processes keystrokes to the foreground window as normal.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau - Interesting thought. I know hooks can do some pretty unique things, so I'll have to look it over to see if there's one that would suit my purpose. Thank you.

Comment: A [low-level keyboard hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644985(v=vs.85)) can filter out keyboard events: *"If the hook procedure processed the message, it may **return a nonzero value to prevent the system from passing the message to** the rest of the hook chain or **the target window procedure**."*

Comment: @JohnMeschke Raw Input triggers before hooks, so Raw Input can detect the device's input first and set a flag, then the hook can ignore the corresponding input when it sees it. Unfortunately, it is not a perfect solution, and there are gotchas to watch out for. [Combining Raw Input and keyboard Hook to selectively block input from multiple keyboards](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/716591/Combining-Raw-Input-and-keyboard-Hook-to-selective)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for that article. Implementing both raw input and a keyboard hook for blocking has proved to be the solution I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some additional testing, blocking with a `WH_KEYBOARD` hook was only partially reliable. It did not work with the newer-style Windows Store applications or higher-level ones, even after moving the DLL and adjusting the permissions as I have read from others. Furthermore, it would often miss out or get duplicate hook messages depending on what I was trying to do.

`WH_KEYBOARD_LL` was more reliable, but it could not be used because it came before the raw input messages which identified the device.

I've come to the conclusion that the only reliable way to do this is through low-level driver/kernel programming. That's a completely different can of worms, and I'm not going to look for a can opener.